# At what g force do bacteria start to pellet down a tube?

Tags: bacteriology, lab-techniques, protocol, animal-models

I am working with *C. elegans* and bacteria and I want to get rid of the bacteria they eat by centrifuging the worms without centrifuging the bacteria. I am using a g-force of 600 and the bacteria sometimes still centrifuge down. What g-force would be ideal to pellet the worms but not the bacteria? Does this depend on the bacterial species?

Comment: Have you tried using Ficoll to separate them?

Comment: no, how does it work? The wikipedia page mentions its use for blood cells separation.